# Adding new functionality to all of shelve.Shelf's subclasses in Python

Tags: design-patterns, python, object-oriented-design, inheritance

In order to avoid the overhead associated with the [shelve module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shelve.py)'s `writeback` option I'm interested in putting together a shelf class that only accepts hashable values, with hashability being a proxy for immutability. So I'd like to subclass `shelve.Shelf` and override the `__set__` method. The catch is that `shelve.open` can return one of a number of different classes (e.g., `Dbfilenameshelf`), and I'd like my code to allow `shelve` this flexibility.

Ideally a solution would have the following properties:

1. No need to wrap every function that `Shelf` provides, as in: `def keys(self): return self._shelf.keys()`
2. Will not break if Python adds new methods to `Shelf` or new subclasses of `Shelf`
3. Avoiding fragility, by which I mean doing something complicated that could easily trip up someone (conceivably me) who is modifying or using the code months or years down the road. An example in this context would be reassigning `Shelf.__set__`, as in `Shelf.__set__ = my_func`. To me defining a new `__getattr__` as @Winston hesitantly offers seems moderately fragile--I take it that's why he suggests it only with hesitation

Less important but still desirable would be:

1. Consistent with object-oriented design principles. It seems to me that the new class here *is a* shelf, not that it *has a* shelf. And probably not both (it's not a shelf which contains another shelf)

Comment: What do you mean by "correct?"

Comment: This question has been edited in an attempt to fix the issues that led to it being put on hold. I'm posting as much here on the seeming advice of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19128)

Answer (score 1):

Don't subclass `shelve.Self`, instead define a new class with a constructor that that calls `shelve.open`. Implement the method of interest by calling the actual methods on the returned shelf object.

Comment: I believe this approach requires me to wrap every method of Shelf, like `def keys(self): return self._shelf.keys()`. Is that correct?

Comment: @kuzzooroo, well, you could override `__getattr__` to forward everything to `_shelf`. I'd figure you probably only need a couple of the methods for what's actually useful in a shelf, and so I'd just implement those directly.